# How to set the bootorder for a vm in vsphere 5.x with pysphere

Tags: python, esxi

I am using the following python code to set the extra_config parameter bios.bootOrder:

```
#!/bin/env python
from pysphere import VIServer, VITask
from pysphere.resources import VimService_services as VI

server = VIServer()
server.connect("vcenter-server", "myusername", "supersecrete")

vm = server.get_vm_by_name( 'targetvm' )
vm.set_extra_config({'bios.bootOrder': 'cdrom,hdd'}, sync_run=True)
```

Unfortunately the reconfiguration task finishes successfully but the boot sequence does not change.
Reportedly the script worked with ESXi 4.x.

May anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. The API changed with vSphere 5. Therefore the above code does not work anymore.

... may helpful for someone else: https://gist.github.com/st0ne-dot-at/9984414

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly crude script, but serves the purpose of an example that uses pyvmomi to set the boot order to cd, works equally well for booting from the network(pxe) booting VM's too:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
import time
import atexit
import argparse
from pyVmomi import vim, vmodl
from pyVim import connect
from pyVim.connect import Disconnect, SmartConnect, GetSi

system = sys.argv[1]

        inputs = {'vcenter_ip': 'ip.ad.re.ss',
          'vcenter_password': 'passwd',
          'vcenter_user': 'user',
          'vm_name' : system,
          'operation' : 'stop',
          'force' : True,
          }

# Functions

def get_obj(content, vimtype, name):
    objct = None
    container = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, vimtype, True)
    for c in container.view:
        if c.name == name:
            objct = c
            break
    return objct


si = connect.Connect(inputs['vcenter_ip'], 443, inputs['vcenter_user'], inputs['vcenter_password'])
content = si.RetrieveContent()
vm = get_obj(content, [vim.VirtualMachine], inputs['vm_name'])
vm.PowerOff()


# Set to boot from cd/network. #'d out is what you'd use for network/pxe booting

#bn                  = vim.option.OptionValue(key='bios.bootDeviceClasses',value='allow:cd')
bn                  = vim.option.OptionValue(key='bios.bootDeviceClasses',value='allow:net')
vmconf              = vim.vm.ConfigSpec()
vmconf.extraConfig  = [bn]
vm.ReconfigVM_Task(vmconf)
time.sleep(10)
vm.PowerOnVM_Task()
time.sleep(30)


# Set system to boot from hdd again

bn                  = vim.option.OptionValue(key='bios.bootDeviceClasses',value='allow:hd,cd,fd,net')
vmconf              = vim.vm.ConfigSpec()
vmconf.extraConfig  = [bn]
vm.ReconfigVM_Task(vmconf)
```